# mongodb on cloud foundry / appfog

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud-foundry, appfog

I am deploying nodejs app with mongodb db with collections/data in it. I have it under the data/db directory. it doesn't have username / password. but with the appfog the service has the user name/password. how does the mongodb service know to start with the db I deployed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you create the MongoDB client you should pass server host/port and authentication information to it.

usually on hosted services such as Heroku or Appfog this info is provided in evncironment variables which can be accessed with `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`